# How can I mount a .hdd file?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I want to add some files to a .hdd file, but I do not know how I can mount it. Is this possible, or is there a program that can help me do this?

Comment: According to [this](http://fileinfo.com/extension/hdd), .hdd files are proprietary Parallels Desktop VHD files. You need Parallels and a Mac to open them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide to converting Parallels virtual machines for use on KVM on Linux:

https://vanappdeveloper.com/2013/07/04/converting-parallels-vm-to-linux-kvm/

To summarise, you'll need to open the hdd file on your Mac (with Parallels installed) with "Show package contents", extract the .hds file, and then on Linux you can use Qemu to convert this .hds file from Parallels format to another VM format.  In the case of that guide, to qcow2 format which is a Qemu format.

Relevant part:

> From the command-line, run the following (substituting xxx for the name of your .hds file
>
> ```
> sudo qemu-img convert -c -p -f parallels -O qcow2  xxx.hds  myNewVM.qcow2
> ```
>
> This should start the conversion, which in my case took a few hours for a 40 GB  hds file.  Man page details on the qemu-img convert command line options is here.
>
> Copy or move the newly created qcow2 VM image to the images directory:
>   sudo mv myNewVM.qcow2 /var/lib/libvirt/images